# If restricted module is projective, does left inverse exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module

Let $\iota:B \to A$ a ring homomorphism. If there is a map $\pi:A \to B$, s.t. $\pi(\iota(b)a) = b\pi(a)$ for all $a \in A$, $b \in B$, then $A$ is projective as a left $B$-module. Is the converse true?

Comment: In what sense is $\pi$ an inverse of $\iota$? As a homomorphism of rings?  As a homomorphism of $B$-modules? The condition you stated is satisfied by the constant map to zero, but that doesn't imply anything.

Comment: Sorry,  I think I also want $\pi(1)=1$... Then the condition already implies that it must be a set-theoretic left inverse

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the clarification. I was originally mislead, but that was due to not reading everything :-)

Comment: Hmm. But won't this variant have counterexamples like $B=\Bbb{Z}_6$, $A=\Bbb{Z}_3$, $\iota(\overline{n})=\overline{n}$? As a $B$-module $A$ is isomorphic to the ideal $I_1=\langle\overline{2}\rangle\subset B$. With $I_2=\langle\overline{3}\rangle\subset B$ we have $B=I_1\oplus I_2$. So $A$ is projective as a direct summand of the free module $B$. There cannot be a homomorphism $\pi:A\to B$ of $B$-modules such that $\pi(1)=1$ because the orders don't match. Or did I confuse myself again :-)

Comment: okay, now i'm sure: 1. i don't want $\pi(1)=1$, just the condition 2. therefore $\pi$ it is not necessarily a left inverse

Comment: The existence of $\pi$ simply says that there is a left $B$-module homomorphism from $A$ to $B$, which definitely doesn’t imply that $A$ is projective as a left $B$-module, even if you require $\pi$ to be nonzero.